# Оперировать или апеллировать

Tags: употребление-слов

Как правильно употреблять слова "апеллировать" и "оперировать"?
"Оперировать фактами"
"Апеллировать фактами" или
"Апеллировать к фактам".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Информация из словарей.

АПЕЛЛИРОВАТЬ к кому-чему.
Обратиться - обращаться за пониманием, поддержкой, советом и т.п. Апеллировать к массам. А. к общественному мнению. 
ОПЕРИРОВАТЬ  чем. Пользоваться чем-л. при рассуждениях, подсчётах, доказательствах и т.п. О. фактами. О. цифрами.

Таким образом,оперировать фактами можно, а вот можно ли апеллировать к фактам? Это вызывает у пользователей сомнение.

Цитаты: (1)"Не могу согласиться с формулировкой :"Апеллировать к фактам" :( Это - грубая калька? Или так можно говорить? Этот вопрос я задала давно, а Грамота.ру всё ещё молчит)." (2) "А вот у слова "апеллировать" значений гораздо меньше. И поэтому аппелировать к общественному мнению можно, но к фактам - нельзя". (3)"Для сравнения уточним: нельзя, разумеется, апеллировать к бессловесным предметам, например, к памятнику Юрию Долгорукому или к автомату Калашникова".

Думаю, что апеллировать к фактам, то есть обращаться к фактам и ждать от них ответа, не стоит. Они вряд ли ответят. Поэтому лучше просто к ним обращаться и учитывать их.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно апеллировать. Оперировать - это хирургический термин

Comment: Глагол "оперировать" имеет несколько значений (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), наше — четвертое. Из Нацкорпуса: Андрей привык **оперировать фактами**, а не эмоциями: «Бомштейн ― явный псих. [Вадим Громов. Компромат для олигарха (2000)] Я не могу строить предположения, а должен **оперировать фактами**. [Анатолий Кучерена. Бал беззакония (2000)]